# Rails, Popups, Ajax deletes and stopPropagation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, jquery, stoppropagation

I have a rails project that has a standard rails delete link inside a popup.

I have multiple popups on the page so I have a **hide action attached to the body (onclick)** and a **stopPropagation event attached to popups** so that clicking inside the popup doesn't hide it, but clicking anywhere else will hide all popups.

However, this seems to be affecting my delete links, which are inside the popups. It seems to be forcing them to get instead of post, which means they're not deleting. And the confirm dialog doesn't appear.

If I move the delete links outside of the popup, it works as expected.

Some code:

```
$('body').click(function() {
    $('.popover').hide();
});
$('.popover').click(function(ev){
    ev.stopPropagation();
});
```

And the rails (Haml) view:

```
.popover
    = link_to [task], :confirm => 'Are you sure you want to delete?', :method => :delete, :remote => true
```

How do I get delete to work inside a parent with stopPropagation?

Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

Use the jQuery `.not()` function in combination with the CSS `*` selector:

```
$('body *').not('.popover, .popover *').click(function() {
    $('.popover').hide();
});
```

Full documentation: http://api.jquery.com/not/

Working JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ryanbrodie/nGcaP/7/

Comment: The problem with this is that the children of the popover element still hide the popover http://jsfiddle.net/nGcaP/2/ unless I'm missing something

Answer (score -1):

The reason why it is not working, is because these of these lines.

```
$('.popover').click(function(ev){
   ev.stopPropagation();
});
```

They stop all javascript from being executed on anything clicked on inside your popups. This will turn your links into standard links without any javascript, thus not performing an post request.

You can solve this by using jQuery's not along with the `*` selector as RyanBrodie suggested.

```
$('body *').not('.popover').click(function() {
  $('.popover').hide();
});
```

To ensure elements within the popover don't trigger hiding the popover do this:

```
$('body *').not('.popover').not('.popover *').click(function() {
  $('.popover').hide();
});
```

Comment: My popover has many children (buttons, forms etc.) is there a way to ensure these elements don't hide the popover when clicked? http://jsfiddle.net/nGcaP/3/

Comment: Yes you can do so like this. http://jsfiddle.net/arjan0307/TemQU/. I'll also update my answer.

Comment: Not necessary to run the function twice, see my answer.